# Missing Cocoapods frameworks in Xcode Proj

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, apple-m1

I created a brand new iOS game application and ran 'pod install' using the Podfile in the screenshot. The project will build and run just fine despite the missing frameworks. I can delete the references in the Navigator but running 'pod install' will put them back.

[image: Screenshot]

Note: I'm on an M1 macbook, not sure if this is expected behavior when using ARM architecture. Has anyone seen this before?

I'm running the following:
CocoaPods : 1.13.0
Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
RubyGems : 3.4.10
Host : macOS 13.4.1 ((c))
Xcode : 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Git : git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Swift Package Manager instead of cocoapods and no more missing framework links

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to resolve the issue:

1. It might expected that the cocoa pods didn't install properly at first step. Please follow the steps and try again.

a) Try deleting pods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod clean
rm Podfile
```

b) Install pods again:

```
pod init
pod install
```

2. You're probably missing the target block for your target, in the
   Podfile.

In my case, I added a target to my project, and forgot to add a target block to the Podfile for that target, and I had the same error.

*(My project)/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-(My project)/Pods-(My project)-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
The path components are actually named after the target:
(My project)/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-[target]/Pods-[target]-frameworks.sh*

Cocoapods builds configuration files for each target that you specify. Try adding a target entry to your Podfile, like so:

```
target "SOME TARGET" do
    specify pods here
end
```

If the above two solutions are not enough to fix your issue, then the final solution : Touch "Build Phases" -> "Embed Pods Frameworks" ,you can see the path :XXXXX.sh" Be sure that the XXX.sh is the same as your project's. if not, change the path. Then clean and build. It's done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately none of these solutions fixed the issue. 'pod install' still brings back the missing framework references.